# Запятая в случае И...И

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Как можно доказать, что и само отшельничество(,) и отвращение к мирским удовольствиям не относятся к числу самых основных и самых важных мирских наслаждений?!
Вроде как должна быть запятая (которая в скобках). Или я что-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая в данном случае ставится **по обшему правилу для повторяющихся союзов** И...И.:

*Как можно доказать, что **и самО отшельничество, и отвращение к мирским удовОльствиям** не относятся к числу самых основных и самых важных мирских наслаждений?!*

Запятая не ставится **в виде исключения** при тесном единстве однородных членов, **не имеющих зависимых слов**, когда их можно прочитать в одну слитную фразу. В данном случае каждый однородный член имеет **зависимые слова**.

Таким образом, при применении правила важно учитывать структуру конкрктного предложения, а не общую схему.

**Правило  Розенталя**

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101

1. Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимися союзами и…и, да…да, ни…ни, или…или, либо…либо, то…то, не то…не то и др., ставится запятая:
2. При двух однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимся союзом И...И, запятая не ставится, если образуется **тесное смысловое единство** (обычно такие однородные члены **не имеют при себе пояснительных слов**): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же время.

Такие смысловые единства образуются словами **с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями:** и брат и сестра, и друзья и враги, и зимой и летом и т.д

3. При **наличии пояснительных слов при одном из двух однородных членов** предложения между ними ставится запятая: Срубленные осины придавили собой и траву, и мелкий кустарник (Т.); Всё вокруг переменилось: и природа, и характер леса (Л. Т.).

Answer (score 4):

Да, запятую следует поставить.

> § 146. Запятая ставится между однородными членами предложения, соединенными посредством повторяющихся союзов: ***и...и, да...да, то...то, ли...ли, или...или*** и т. п.

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/147-zap-19-27).

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствие запятой можно мотивировать тем, что эти два И не являются повторяющимся союзом. В нашем случае можно первое из двух И трактовать как усилительную частицу в значении "тоже", "также", "как и".  Правда для этого нужен определенный контекст, который в вопросе не представлен.

Придумывать за автора правдоподобный контекст здесь сложно, фраза весьма специфична по смысловой  по нагрузке, поэтому рассмотрим условный пример.
*Петя вчера гулял в парке. Как можно показать, и Маша с Васей там тоже гуляли*.
Здесь И, если и союз, то непарный (хотя вернее всего это частица, но не важно).

Теперь заменяем "Маша с Васей" на на эквивалентную конструкцию "Маша и Вася" запятой явно не требующую. Получаем
***Петя вчера гулял в парке. Как можно показать, и Маша и Вася там тоже гуляли***.
Так что автор, если он видит предложение именно таким, формально прав.
Другое дело, что редакторы обычно в таких случаях тоже упираются до последнего, им всегда проще свести все к простому, явно описанному в Правилах случаю.

Так что в исходном примере для обоснования отсутвия запятой нужен a) определенный контекст, б) упрямство автора.